# From where i can find the PublicKeyToken & Version for my <membership> <providers>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, ldap

I am working with an asp.net mvc web application, and i need to connect to remote domain, so i added the following to my web.config:-

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="....." connectionPassword="....." />
```

but i am not sure what does Version and PublicKeyToken represetns and from where i can find them ? and if i do not specify these values will my provider be valid ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As that's a regular framework assembly, it will be deployed on GAC; to discover full assembly name you can access that class documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There you'll find that class resides on System.Web assembly. Now you can navigate to `c:\windows\assembly` folder and locate the assembly which matches desired version, right click it and copy the public key token.

Is that information doesn't match the version and public key token on your web.config file, .NET framework can't locate it and, you'll get a missing assembly exception.

Comment: so you mean the .net version for the server hosting the .net application, or the version for the active directory server ?

Comment: Depends on your .net application version; is you compiled it with 4.0 framework, you should ask your hosting provider for an application pool for that version. The active directory version doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: but to be honest i removed the version and public key token and all the values inside the type. then i only specify the type as type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" . and i could connect to my AD without any problems . So in my case maybe knowing the version and public key token is not essential, can you advice ?

Comment: You can have different assembly versions on GAC, that's why you probably will want to add it sometime